# Рефлексия и репродуктивность (о новых терминах в нашем образовании)

Tags: общие-вопросы, методика

1) В учебном пособии для первого класса (тоненькая брошюрка с детскими картинками) мне встретились такие выражения, как **репродуктивная и продуктивная учебная деятельность.**

**ПРОДУКТИВНЫЙ**,  [лат. productivus] 1. Приносящий результаты, создающий ценности; производительный, плодотворный. **РЕПРОДУКТИВНЫЙ** – от репродукция, воспроизводящий.

Как оценить методику образования по этой шкале?  Всё, что не связано с самостоятельной учебной деятельностью, с осознанным выбором в условиях неопределенности, названо деятельностью **репродуктивной (воспроизводящей).**

Вероятно, это знания в готовом виде, их безальтернативное усвоение. А усваивать их действительно тяжело и не всегда интересно.  Дети быстро устают, когда их головы наполняют такими готовыми знаниями, когда  нет интриги, нет выбора, не надо думать. Увы, меня, скорее всего, учили **по репродуктивным методикам.**

**Говорят, что "всё новое – это хорошо забытье старое".** [https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/dic_wingwords/514/Всё](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/dic_wingwords/514/%D0%92%D1%81%D1%91)

Подобный подход к образованию ранее  применялся **в методиках развивающего обучения.**

2) **Второй термин – это рефлексия,** нечто  совсем непонятное. РЕФЛЕКСИЯ,  [от лат. reflexio – обращение назад] Книжн. Размышление о своих чувствах, анализ своих переживаний.

Предлагается развивать у школьников **языковую рефлексию** (?) Они должны **рефлексивно** (?)  осознавать изменения в поставленной задаче, планировать способ действия в измененных условиях, осуществлять контроль, извлекать информацию и т.д.

Вот такими должны быть первоклассники в современной школе. Родители, возможно, думают, что учительница научит ребенка читать и писать, готовиться самим не нужно? Тогда вот вам две картинки, две крайности. Это Аля, она занимается науками с четырех лет, отличница-второклассница с постоянно грустными глазами. (Правда,   больше всего на свете она любит танцы, а школу не любит). А это первоклассница Варя, она плачет на уроках. Почему? Если она не знает ответа на вопрос, то опускает голову и плачет. Бедная Варя.

**И вопрос:**

**Эти термины (рефлексия, продуктивная и репродуктивная деятельность**) – это действительно нечто новое и прогрессивное в оценке процесса обучения? Насколько они точны и уместны, можно ли вообще ими пользоваться? 
И насколько такой подход известен и распространен в современных школах?

Comment: Под **языковой рефлексией** здесь понимают анализ человеком (ребёнком в данном случае) особенностей своей речи. Рефлексия вообще начинает формироваться в младшем школьном возрасте. Не вижу ничего плохого, если учитель младших классов будет понимать, что это такое, и помогать ребёнку в процессе воспитания. Можно ли обойтись без использования сложного научного термина в методичке? Думаю, да, особенно, если речь идёт об учителе со средним специальным образованием.

Comment: Без примеров непонятно. По-моему, когда ребенок говорит ав-ав при виде собаки, он уже размышляет о своих чувствах и анализирует свои переживания. К тому же вступительная статья в учебном пособии обращена к учителям и родителям, а не к детям, это учителя  должны развивать рефлексию у детей. А делать это надо, внося изменения в условия задачи,  чтобы дети на это реагировали. Но почему эта реакция называется именно языковой рефлексией, а не просто рефлексией?

Comment: Кстати, там есть довольно милый пример на тему "многозначные слова":Едет Зайка на трамвае, Едет Зайка, рассуждая: «Если я купил билет, Кто я : заяц или нет?» Может быть, в таких ситуациях проявляется языковая рефлексия?

Comment: Ксения, думаю, будет продуктивнее :) почитать какой-нибудь учебник по психологии, чем пытаться в твиттер-формате строить теорию формирования личности в комментариях на форуме, посвящённом русскому языку.

Comment: А при чем тут формирование личности? Речь идет о методике преподавания  языка.  Большинство детей уже в первом классе любят математику больше, чем  русский язык. Почему? Отвечают, что им нравится считать. Но я полагаю, что им нравится думать, действовать, принимать решения. Русский язык - это не только правописание, которое за 11 лет выучить не могут. Вот стилистику изучают в школе как серьезный предмет? Вряд ли, времени на это не хватает. А эта наука  не менее важная, чем умение ставить запятые и объяснять их на форуме, посвящённому русскому языку.

Comment: *А при чем тут формирование личности?* — я говорю об этом: "когда ребенок говорит ав-ав при виде собаки, он уже размышляет о своих чувствах и анализирует свои переживания". Это неверно, но я не вижу способа убедить Вас. А что касается математики, то из всех наук лингвистика ближе всех к математике (я как математик могу смело утверждать это). Но по сути Ваших вопросов мне сказать нечего, я хотел только прокомментировать один термин (языковая рефлексия).

Comment: Мне кажется, что деятельность в первом абзаце должна была быть **непродуктивная**, а не **репродуктивная**.

Comment: Да, Вы правы, я исправила текст.